# How can I define a metric for uniqueness of strings on Django model?

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, relational-database

Suppose I have a model that represents scientific articles. Doing some research, I may find the same article more than once, with approximately equal titles:

- `Some Article Title`
- `Some Article  Title`

Notice that the second title string is slightly different: it has an extra space before "Title".

If the problem was because there could be more or less spacing, it would be easy since I could just trim it before saving.

But say there could be more small differences that consist of characters other than spaces:

- `Comparison of machine learning techniques to predict all-cause mortality using fitness data: the Henry ford exercIse testing (FIT) project.`
- `Comparison of machine learning techniques to predict all-cause mortality using fitness data: the Henry ford exercIse testing (FIT).`

*This is some random article I used here as an example*

Those titles clearly refer to the same unique work, but the second one for some reason is missing some letters.

**What is the best way of defining uniqueness in this situation?**

In my mind, I was thinking of some function that calculates the levenshtein distance and decides if the strings are the same title based on some threshold. **But is it possible to do on a django model, or define this behavior on a database level?**

Comment: Nope not possible just with django

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was the levenshtein distance too, so it's probably the way to go here ;) You could implement it yourself or find the code that already knows how to compute it (there's a lot of them) and then...

...use it in the model validation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

You can basically raise an exception in the custom `validate_unique` if you decide the new object violates this special type of uniqueness. The flipside is you'll probably need to load all other objects there.

If you create these objects on your own, you'll have to call `full_clean()` explicitly before saving. If the articles come from some kind of form, calling `is_valid()` on that form is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have `2` options here, `0` of which are perfect.

---

## Option 1

This assumes you have a function `titles_are_similar(title_1: str, title_2: str): bool` implemented, that decides whether the two titles are similar. Use any sort of fuzzy string comparison of your choice to implement this function.

We will need to use an enhanced [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/).

- I said "enhanced" because it will optionally accept the object you are currently trying to save, when a typical django validator for obvious reasons does not do so.
- The current object's `id` is required. When you change and save an already existing instance/row `x`, validation should **not** fail because the table already contains a "similar" value that belongs to this exact instance/row `x`.

The validator itself will use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to reduce the performance impact.

```
def title_unique_enough_validator(value, exclude_obj=None):
    query_set = Article.objects.all()
    if exclude_obj:
        query_set = query_set.exclude(pk=exclude_obj.pk)  # pk -> id
    old_titles = query_set.values_list("title", flat=True)
    if any(titles_are_similar(old_title, new_title) for old_title in old_titles):
        raise ValidationError("Similar title already exists")  # also use _()
```

If you will use: `title = models.CharField(validators=[title_unique_enough_validator], ...)` you will get a `ValidationError` every time you try to modify and save an existing object, as this object is not passed into the validator and therefore not excluded from the check (I mentioned it above). Instead, we will override the `Article.clean()` method ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)):

```
class Article(Model):
...
def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    title_unique_enough_validator(value=self.title, obj=self)
```

It will nicely work with forms. But there are 2 other major problems left.

#### Problem 1

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

> Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.

To solve this, override the `.save()` method:

```
class Article(...):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        title_unique_enough_validator(value=self.value, obj=self)  # can raise ValidationError
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, django does not expect to have a `ValidationError` when calling `save()`. So, every time you manually call `article.save()` from your Python code (without djano forms) you need to wrap it into a `try ... except` block. Otherwise your software will [500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) on `ValidationError`.

#### Problem 2

Do you ever explicitly call `Article.objects.update()`? If so, bad news ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update)):

> update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models

As a workaround, you might want to [create a custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/) for the `Article` model and override the `update()`: simply make it unusable (`raise NotImplemented`), or implement an additional check there. Just something that will prevent it from violating your constraint.

---

## Option 2

Use [database constraints](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=SQL%20constraints).

Why I did not list this option first? Well, you will encounter **tons and tons of problems** with it. Django is not aware what database constraints might do. It just dies with `OperationalError` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions)) every time a constraint prevents it from doing what it wants.

As I have to work with many [unmanaged models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed) using django, I can confirm that you will require crap load of efforts to enhance django classes, so that it can deal with the `OperationalError` every now and then without exploding every bloody time. Especially painful is to deal with it if you're using `django.contrib.admin`, as it's just an endless pile of spaghetti.

So, seriously, avoid database constraints, unless you already must use [unmanaged models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed) or you're a masochist in search of adventures.